# Javascript OnSubmit isn't working for the second time

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, onsubmit

My javascript script that is suppose to replace the inner HTML of a div element every time a form is submit isn't working for the second time

Here's my Javascript code:

```
function TryCode(code, gametype, gameid) {
    var tries = "1";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        var element = document.getElementById("A" + i).innerHTML;
        var element2 = element.replace(/^\s+/, '');
        if (element2 == '') {
            tries = i;
            break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == 'success') {
                ActivateUnloadComfirmation = "0";
                document.location.href = "index.php?success=1";
            } else if (xmlhttp.responseText == 'fail') {
                ActivateUnloadComfirmation = "0";
                document.location.href = "index.php?fail=1";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("Try" + tries).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "system/trylogger.php?code=" + code + "&tries=" + tries + "&gameid=" + gameid + "&gametype=" + gametype, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

HTML DIV CODE

```
<table width="40%">
<tr>
    <td id="Try1" width="58%">
        <div class="tries_container" style="float: left;margin-right: 49px;">
        </div>
        <div class="tries_container" style="width: 15px;float: left;margin-right: 8px;" id="A1">
        </div>
        <div class="tries_container" style="width: 15px;float: left;">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

HTML FORM CODE

```
<form onsubmit="TryCode(this.code.value, '{$GameType}', '{$GameID}'); return false;">
<input type="text" name="code" maxlength="4" pattern="[0-9]{4}" title="4 digit code" placeholder="Code" required>
</br>
</br>
<input type="submit" id="try_button" value="Try This Code">
```

At first, it does change the inner HTML of id Try1 but when I click the submit button again, it doesn't change the inner HTML of Try2.

Sorry for my bad code, I'm very new with Javascript

Comment: The HTML you've posted does not contain an element with `id="Try2"`.  Does one exist?

Comment: Yeah it does, sorry, I posted this at 3 am I forgot about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the example code you've provided is all you have, Try2 and A2 are missing. Otherwise, try maintaining the current 'try' using a global variable instead of looping through your elements to look for the empty one.

Example HTML:

```
<tr>
<td id="Try1" width="50%">
    <div class="tries_container" style="float: left;margin-right: 49px;">
    </div>
    <div class="tries_container" style="width: 15px;float: left;margin-right: 8px;" id="A1">
    </div>
    <div class="tries_container" style="width: 15px;float: left;">
    </div>
</td>
<td id="Try2" width="50%">
    <div class="tries_container" style="float: left;margin-right: 49px;">
    </div>
    <div class="tries_container" style="width: 15px;float: left;margin-right: 8px;" id="A2">
    </div>
    <div class="tries_container" style="width: 15px;float: left;">
    </div>
</td>
```

Greatly simplified Javascript:

```
var tries = 1;

function TryCode(code, gametype, gameid) {
    document.getElementById("Try" + tries).innerHTML = "TEST";
    tries++;
}
```

In my example, the "Try2" and "A2" elements are added and "tries" is moved outside of the function becoming the global "tries" variable that I can use throughout my application.

Also, if you need to persist the number of tries through different page loads you will have to put it in the URL as a parameter and retrieve it after the page loads. It appears as though you are passing it as a parameter but you're not retrieving it after the page loads.

[This tells you how to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

Comment: Thanks man, it works. I just set car tries as a global variable and put an increment every time I call the function